# Generic Helper Method vs Direct Class Casting?

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently doin' like this.

```java
static <T extends Some> T doSome(Class<T> type, T obj) {
    // pre-existing legacy method
    // omitted for brevity
}

private static <T extends Some> T doSomeHelper(Class<T> type, Some obj) {
    // private!
    // only invoked from doSome(T) 
    return doSome(type, type.cast(obj));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T extends Some> T doSome(T obj) {
    return (T) doSomeHelper(obj.getClass(), obj);
}
```

I just found that following method also has no problem with the compiler.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Some> T doSome_(T obj) {
    return doSome((Class<T>) obj.getClass(), obj);
}
```

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is better, because all the types are correct on a theoretical level.

In the second way, the cast `(Class<T>) obj.getClass()` is not theoretically correct. `obj`'s actual runtime class can be any subtype of `T`, and therefore `obj.getClass()` can be `Class<some subtype of T>`, which is not compatible with `Class<T>`. The cast won't actually fail at runtime due to type erasure, but you should not write code that is not theoretically correct.

Answer (score 0):

In `doSomeHelper` in the first method, `type.cast(obj)` is not safe because it would fail if `obj.getClass() == Some.class` and `type == SubtypeOfSome.class`. `<T super Some>` would be safe (type is a consumer of obj).

The second method is better, because although you are having to cast (since `obj.getClass()` is of type `Class<? extends T>`), it is safely castable to `Class<T>` since it is derived directly from `obj`.

It's not really obvious from the code provided, however, why you need the overload - why can't `// for brevity` be implemented in `doSome(T obj)`?

Comment: "In doSomeHelper in the first method, type.cast(obj) is not safe because it would fail if obj.getClass() == Some.class and type == SubtypeOfSome.class." That doesn't make any sense. `obj.getClass()` is the argument that is passed for the parameter `type`. So they are the same.